# Function lme and lmer problem understanding error messages in R

Tags: r, lme4, mixed-models

I need to build a GLMM with [this dataset](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1mFeeXopren2VbyoDKmC7Qb5kcl6BogEVjHedCUARW08/edit?usp=sharing) having MGFrew as dependent variable, Sex and Rew_on as fixed effects, and ID as random effect.
I have tried with

```
model1=lme(fixed = MGFrew~Sex*Rew_on, data=Test1, random=~1|ID)
```

But I get this error message that I am not sure how to interpret: Error in getGroups.data.frame(dataMix, groups) : invalid formula for groups. Should I make changes in the way in which I present the fixed effects? I also tried removing Rew_on from the formula, but it gives the same error message.

Then I tried with the function lmer

```
model2=lmer (MGFrew~ Sex  + Rew_on + (1|ID), data=Test1)
```

But according to error messages, I cannot include ID as a random effect, since the number of levels of each grouping factor must be < number of observations. In the end, I could build a model just with this settings, which are not the ones I wanted:

```
model3<-lmer (MGFrew~ Sex  + (1|Rew_on), data=Test1)
```

Could you help me understanding if the model I want to build is possible with these functions, and if so, which changes I need to make and where?

Comment: I don't see repeated measures in this dataset. Each ID seems to appear only once. That would suggest you shouldn't use a mixed effects model.

Comment: You aren ot craeting a GLMM but a LMM which is fit using different methods. I'd be adding to Rolands voice here. If you have only one observation per ID it makes little sense to use a mixed model. Some authors continue to use it, in the generalized poisson model, at which point it would be (i believe) equivalent to fitting a dispersion parameter. I'd suggest moving away from mixed models on this specific dataset and use a linear regression, unless your ID's are repeated measurements.